# How do I need to configure the macOS logging system to log LOG_INFO messages from Perl?

Tags: logs, macports, perl

In the dovecot port for macOS in MacPorts, there is a pushnotify capability (requires you to be able to create the right certificates). This is perl code that contains the following snippet:

```
# Open the socket to Dovecot
unlink $sockpath;
umask (0111);
my $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
Type   => SOCK_DGRAM,
Local  => $sockpath,
Listen => SOMAXCONN,
)
or die("Can't create server socket: $!\n");

drop_privileges($user);

openlog ('apns', 'ndelay', 'mail');

# When we last checked the feedback service (right now, never).
my $last_feedback = 0;
# When we last reconnected to APNS
my $last_connect = 0;

# We'll defer connecting to APNS until our first notification, but define $apns here
my $apns;

syslog (LOG_INFO, 'Dovecot APNS service running');
```

Supposedly, this code wants to log using the old syslog interface. Now ASL supersedes syslog, but it is supposed to be able to catch the syslog stuff as well, when correctly configured. Or so I think. But I am unable to find that logging.

During boot, I see warnings from ASL:

```
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.cdscheduler" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.family.asl" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.callhistory.asl.conf" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.contacts.ContactsUICore" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
        Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
        Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.eventmonitor" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.mail" sharing output destination "/var/log/mail.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
        Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.mail".
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.mail" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.coreaudio" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.iokit.power" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "org.macports.daemon" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.contacts.ContactsAutocomplete" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.mkb" sharing output destination "/private/var/log/keybagd.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.mkb.internal".
        Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.mkb.internal" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.mkb".
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.mkb" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.AddressBookLegacy" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.networking.boringssl" sharing output destination "/Library/Logs/CrashReporter" with ASL Module "com.apple.networking.networkextension".
        Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.networking.networkextension" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.networking.boringssl".
Nov 23 11:20:54 localhost syslogd[58]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.clouddocs" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

which seem to imply that configuration may be an issue here. The perl program tries to send to syslog, syslog will catch it, but because syslog on macOS is ASL it somehow disappears in a black hole, even if there are output files mentioned, they tend to be empty or only have a few unrelated messages. I'd like to get to the bottom of his. Having no logging is killing me.

Comment: I've updated the title to make it more easy to understand that the focus in on configuring the log system, not on programming.

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545047/how-to-write-to-var-log-system-log-on-a-mac

Comment: No. I tried what is mentioned in that item (see there) but I do not see a single syslog message in Console or in `log stream`

Comment: @gctwnl How bizarre. It works great.

Comment: The command line `syslog` command in combination with `log stream` (as mentioned in the other question) works. I can see it in a terminal window. Now the question becomes, how can I tell ASL to dump these 'apns' messages in a file. I wonder what would happen if I do not use the 'mail' facility.